# Carregar arquivo xml em Gridview?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, gridview

Em meu projeto, preciso selecionar um arquivo XML (tabela) do meu tablet e depois ler seu conteúdo e mostrar em uma GridView.

Não sei como começar, alguém tem alguma ideia de como?

Creio que com o código de início vocês conseguem entender o que quero fazer:

```
public class XMLActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnOpen; 
    private GridView tabelaxml; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml);

        btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpen);
        tabelaxml= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.tabelaxml);

        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com GridViews, você precisará de quatro coisas: A Activity (você já possui), uma classe Adapter, que possuirá o conteúdo de cada célula do seu grid, um arquivo xml contendo o layout de cada célula do seu grid e, finalmente, o xml responsável pela sua activity (onde nela terá o seu component GridView)

Para saber melhor como ler arquivos xml, veja [esse link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

Dê uma olhada também [nesse link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/), onde autor explica muito bem como se deve criar um GridView personalizado.

O seu arquivo Adapter irá receber em seu construtor, além de um context, uma lista de objetos (No seu caso, as informações referentes ao seu xml), como no exemplo:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<XmlValores> valoresParametro) {
        this.context = context;
        this.meusValores = valoresParametro;
    }
```

A partir daí, é só trabalhar com seu objeto como bem entender! (:

Comment: Pedro, to meia tapada nesse projeto :// tipo, como eu vou estar lendo o arquivo xml ao "apertar" o botão que vai estar no aplicativo,  não sei como colocar no adapter os valores e muito menos na activity já que supostamente nao sei cada dado do arquivo. Ja estou usando o Imageadapter, a tabela personalizada e algumas dicas nos mesmos links. Tem alguma ideia de como começar na activity?

Answer (score 1):

Ao apertar o botão da sua activity, você poderia chamar uma nova activity, contendo o gridview desejado.

Exemplo:

```
 btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NovaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Na sua "NovaActivity", você irá inicializar da mesma forma que inicia a primeira, porém, o xml da sua activity irá conter o componente GridiView.
Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Esse xml de exemplo serve apenas para dizer ao android que vc terá um grid na sua tela. Para formatar o conteúdo desse grid, você precisará de um adapter e o xml desse adapter. O conteúdo da função "getView()" do adapter é exatamente para a exibição de cada célula de seu gridview. 
Exemplo:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);
```

Nesse trecho eu digo que o componente "grid_item_label" terá como conteúdo a posição "position" do vetor "mobileValues". Ou seja, para cada espaço de seu grid, a função getView() será executada. Agora, o conteúdo de cada célula será determinado por você. O vetor "mobileValues" pode possuir qualquer atributo, basta você apresentá-lo no seu adapter, que ele irá aparecer na tela.

No caso do xml do conteúdo do seu grid, basta inserir os elementos que cada célula terá. No caso do exemplo, o xml teria apenas um texto.

Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:textSize="15px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Você pode não saber os dados do arquivo, mas precisa saber o tipo de dados que irá receber. Esses dados serão armazenados no seu vetor, para que cada posição seja exibida em seu adapter. (: